# Galois groups of polynomial above a field of 17 elements

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Let f(x) be polynomial with a degree 4, which is a separable and irreducible. What are the possible Galois groups above a field with 17 elements of f(x)?

I am a little confused, since 17 is a prime therefore there aren't any sub fields, so isn't the identity ? Am i missing something?

Comment: I suppose the zeros of the polynomial could generate a field of order $17$, $17^2$,  $17^3$ or  $17^4$.

Comment: How does the question of possible Galois extensions of  the field relate to the polynomial f?

Comment: Assuming it is irreducible over the prime field (the only option that makes sense IMO), then you know the roots generate a quartic extension. Because there is only one such....